# Rust lifetime error

Tags: rust, lifetime

Can anyone tell what the lifetime error is in the following code? (simplified from my actual code) I've looked it over myself, but I can't figure out what is wrong or how to fix it. The problem comes when I try to add the `Cell`, but I'm not sure why.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Bar<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a Foo<'a>) -> Bar<'a> { Bar{bar: foo.raw} }
}

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
    cell: Cell<&'a str>,
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get_bar(&self) -> Bar { Bar::new(&self) }
}
```

The compiler error is

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/foo.rs:15:32
   |
15 |     fn get_bar(&self) -> Bar { Bar::new(&self) }
   |                                ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the solution:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Bar<'a> {
    bar: &'a str,
}
impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &Foo<'a>) -> Bar<'a> { Bar{bar: foo.raw} }
}

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
    cell: Cell<&'a str>,
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get_bar(&self) -> Bar<'a> { Bar::new(&self) }
}
```

There are two problems in your code.  The first is with `get_bar`, where you didn't specify the lifetime for the return type.  When you don't specify lifetimes in signatures, Rust doesn't infer the correct lifetimes, it just blindly fills them in based on simple rules.  In this specific case, what you get is effectively `fn get_bar<'b>(&'b self) -> Bar<'b>` which is *obviously* wrong, given the lifetime of `self.raw` (which was what you actually wanted) is `'a`.  See the Rust Book chapter on [Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision).

The second problem is that you're over-constraining the argument to `Bar::new`.  `&'a Foo<'a>` means you require a borrow to a `Foo` for as long as the strings it's borrowing exist.  But borrows within a type have to outlive values of said type, so the *only* lifetime valid in this case is where `'a` matches the entire lifetime of the thing being borrowed... and *that* conflicts with the signature of `get_bar` (where you're saying `&self` won't necessarily live as long as `'a` since it has its own lifetime).  Long story short: remove the unnecessary `'a` from the `Foo` borrow, leaving just `&Foo<'a>`.

To rephrase the above: the problem with `get_bar` was that you hadn't written enough constraints, the problem with `Bar::new` was that you'd written too many.

Comment: @Antimony I'm not certain, but I *think* it has to do with `Cell` having interior mutability which *probably* affects the lifetime variance of the containing type.  Throwing mutability into the mix tends to make the borrow checker stricter.  I'd give a more thorough answer, but this is one aspect that I'm not solid on, myself.

Comment: Good point. I forgot about variance inference. That's probably the answer.

Answer (score 4):

DK explained which constraints were missing and why, but I figured I should explain why the code was working before I added `Cell`. It turns out to be due to [variance inference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

If you add in the inferred lifetimes to the original code and rename the lifetime variables to be unique, you get

```
struct Bar<'b> {
    bar: &'b str,
}
impl<'b> Bar<'b> {
    fn new(foo: &'b Foo<'b>) -> Bar<'b> { Bar{bar: foo.raw} }
}

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    raw: &'a str,
    cell: Cell<&'a str>,
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn get_bar<'c>(&'c self) -> Bar<'c> { Bar::new(&self) }
}
```

The problem comes when calling `Bar::new`, because you are passing `&'c Foo<'a>`, to something expecting `&'b Foo<'b>`. Normally, immutable types in Rust are covariant, meaning that `&Foo<'a>` is implicitly convertable to `&Foo<'b>` whenever 'b is a shorter lifetime than 'a. Without the Cell, `&'c Foo<'a>` converts to `&'c Foo<'c>`, and is passed to `Bar::new` wiht 'b = 'c, so there is no problem.

However, `Cell` adds interior mutability to `Foo`, which means that it is no longer safe to be covariant. This is because `Bar` could potentially try to assign a shorter lived `'b` reference back into the original `Foo`, but `Foo` requires that all of the references it holds are valid for the longer lifetime `'a`. Therefore, interior mutability makes `&Foo` invariant, meaning you can no longer shorten the lifetime parameter implicitly.